# .NET Core Identity server

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-identity

I am trying to develop my student's project -build  WEB API in .net core. So I have some difficulties and if you guys can help me that would be awesome.

1. When should I use authorization with Identity framework and when with JWT Tokens? Which is more used on real world projects?
2. In my services part I have UserManager and SignInManager interfaces and classes. I also have UserService class and they look something like this:

```
 public interface IUserManager
    {
        Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId);
        Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName);
        Task<List<User>> GetAllAsync();
        Task<User> GetCurrentUser(ClaimsPrincipal principal);
        Task<User> CreateUserAsync(User user, string password);
        Task UpdateUserAsync(User user, string currentPassword, string newPassword);
        Task DeleteUserAsync(User user);
        Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleAsync(User user, string role);
        Task<List<string>> GetUserRolesAsync(User user);
        Task ChangePasswordAsync(User user, string currentPassword, string newPassword);
        Task<User> GetUserRolesAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal);
    }
```

```
public interface IUserService
    {
        Task<User> Register(string UserName, string Email, string Password);
        Task<SignInResult> Login(string UserName, string Password);
        Task Logout();
    }
```

```
 public interface ISignInManager
    {
        Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password);
        Task SignOutAsync();
    }
```

---

My question is: is it a good practise to use all three (with dependency injection) in my controllers? Or there is another way to do this? Thank you :)

I tried to follow the Solid principles.

Comment: *When should I use authorization with Identity framework and when with JWT Tokens* An identity framework works great if your app has a direct access to a user registry. JWT tokens work great if your app delegates authentication to an identity provider.

Comment: My in general advice.    Do NOT write your own security token service software.  (1) if you had a 2 teams and a year, you could never close all the gaps that an existing and extendable solution will give you. (2) focus on "your" business, and most of use are not in the STS business, we're in another business but we need to secure our code.             It IS a good idea to inject your interfaces into your webapi controllers.  but you shouldn't make "super webapi controllers" where you have a superset of all methods.     break them down a little bit too.         i add more in the next comment

Comment: What I do when I need multiple "IMyBusinessLogicManager"'s .. is I create (in my business logic layer) a IMySomethingComposer....  and in my concrete MySomethingComposer, I inject the multiple "IMyBusinssLogicManagers"'s into it.  Then I inject IMySomethingComposer into my webapi controller.     this is "software my composition".     Your methods in IMySomethingComposer will prob be a smaller subset of all the methods.  and/OR you will use 2:N IMyBusinessLogicManagers calls in a single IMySomethingComposer method.  This 2:N is loosely related to "Template Design Pattern"

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method/csharp/example